# dnsmasq to server different ip depending on which NS is used

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, dnsmasq

I want to simulate the following situation:

If the client makes a request using NS1 for DOMAIN1 return IP1
If the client makes a request using NS2 for DOMAIN1 return IP2
i.e resolve the domain to a different IP depending on which name server is used in the request.

Is it possible to do this with DNSMasq ? If not, whats the best way to do this ?

Comment: Maybe this is irrelevant, but why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simple spin up two dnsmasq services, each listening on different IP, and each having different databases?

All you need to have different in your config is listen-address.

So, on your NS1, use something like::

```
listen-address=<NS1>
```

and on NS2:

```
listen-addrress=<NS2>
```

coupled with nameserver database.

Comment: Jakov, can you suggest how to get them to listen on different IPs on the same machine ?

Comment: I have wrote the solution - set up two different dnsmasq.conf files with different "listen-address" directives within each of them.